# Converting fishnet polygons into CSV using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ndvi, vector-grid, rusle

I am working on C factor of RUSLE model for a watershed. The objective is to take fortnightly data of the watershed and plot the NDVI values on a graph such that I can estimate the Vegetation cover changes in the area. I have created fishnet feature class but the problem is, I cannot extract the NDVI values from the attribute table since they are not appearing in the attribute table.

Do I need to change the inputs for fishnet extraction?

Such as 'template extent' and 'raster analysis'?

Comment: What software do you use?

Comment: ArcGIS (arcmap 10.3)

Comment: Explain your datasets, like how is your ndvi data stored. Maybe some images would help explain your problem?